# How exactly can I set file permissions to an user in an unix instance?

Tags: unix

I have a user that I want to restrict to a certain number of files. Not a folder specific,but a given set of files (some .css, .js, etc). He can already log in using his private key but this is not yet working as he has full repo access to everything else. How exactly can I eliminate this global access and restrict only to certain files?

Comment: split the users based on user type and by using if condition avoid what are the files you dont want to display

Comment: restrict sensitive file by changing their access permissions. Allow those files to be accessed by specific user/user-groups only.
More help here :https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: @Prashant is there an easier way? I want the user to be able to access only those files, nothing else. Can't I blacklist everything by default and then whitelist the files?

Comment: @Fane You can remove even read permission for those files. And for required files grant read/write permission as required. The link I posted earlier, will help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chown` to set file owner and `chmod` to set file permission

example:
you want to restrict user2 to read write and execute the file script.js, but you want user1 to have full access on it. Then you have to execute this:

First set the file owner.

```
$ chown user1:user1 script.js
```

Then set the permission

```
$ chmod 700 script.js
```

This will restrict every other user from reading, writing and executing  script.js except from user1 and users under the group of user1

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a solution for specific folder use it for file type.Change the access mode of *.js or *.css.